# How do I handle null or optional DLL struct parameters

Tags: c#, null, interop, pinvoke, optional-parameters

How do I deal with optional `struct` arguments in dll methods called from C# using pinvoke? For example, the [`lpSecurityAttributes` parameter here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724917(v=vs.85).aspx) should be passed `null` when absent.

The correct way of passing `struct`'s seems to be using `ref`, but it cannot have optional parameters, or take `null` in general.

What ways are there to achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### You have a few options

#### 1) Use a `class` instead of a `struct`

I think this method is the easiest. Simply declare the `struct` as a `class`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class CStruct
{
    //member-list
}
```

and then declare your method:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", OptionName = optionValue, ...)]
static extern int DLLFunction(CStruct cStruct, ...);
```

If your optional parameter happens to be the last one, you can instead use `CStruct cStruct = null` as the parameter. This allows you to exclude it instead of passing `null` explicitly. You can also write a wrapper method that uses this and ensures the optional parameters come last.

#### 2) Use `IntPtr` and `IntPtr.Zero`

Use a `struct`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CStruct
{
    //member-list
}
```

and declare your method as:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", OptionName = optionValue, ...)]
static extern int DLLFunction(IntPtr cStruct, ...);
```

In the non-`null` case, [marshal the struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83.aspx) to a pointer and call the method:

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CStruct)));
try{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(myCStruct, ptr, false);
    DLLFunction(ptr, ...);
} finally {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

In the `null` case, call the method with `IntPtr.Zero`:

```
DLLFunction(IntPtr.Zero, ...);
```

Again, you can make this parameter optional if this happens to be the last in the list (or you use a wrapper to make it so). Do this by using `IntPtr cStruct = default(IntPtr)` as the parameter. (As `default(IntPtr)` [creates a `IntPtr.Zero`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12999721).)

#### 3) Overload your method to avoid marshaling

Use a `struct` as in **2)**.

Simply declare one option for the non-`null` case:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", OptionName = optionValue, ...)]
static extern int DLLFunction(ref cStruct, ...);
```

and another for the `null` case:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", OptionName = optionValue, ...)]
static extern int DLLFunction(IntPtr cStruct, ...);
```

The first method will automatically get called when passing a `struct`, and the second when passing `IntPtr.Zero`. If declaring the `IntPtr` version with an optional parameter (as shown at the bottom of **2)** above), it will automatically call it when you exclude the `cStruct` parameter.

#### 4) Raw pointers using `unsafe`

Use a struct as in **2)** and declare your method (note the `unsafe` keyword):

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", OptionName = optionValue, ...)]
static unsafe extern int DLLFunction(CStruct* cStruct, ...);
```

In the non-`null` case, you pass `&myCStruct`, and simply `null` in the `null` case. As in **1)**, if this optional parameter is last, you can declare the parameter as `CStruct* cStruct = null` to automatically pass `null` when `cStruct` is excluded.

<sup>Thanks to @dialer for suggesting this method.</sup>

Comment: You can also (read: my personal favorite is) declare the P/Invoke signature using unsafe pointers. `static unsafe extern int DLLFunction(TheStruct* struct, ...);`. This has several advantages. You can use an actual value type instead of a reference type (relevant if stack alloc performance matters), can pass `null`, don't need another overload, no marshaling (actually enforces it to be blittable even, which in turn increases performance again) and it's type-safe (unlike `IntPtr`). The obvious downside is that you have to use `unsafe` (though to be fair using `IntPtr` is *not* any safer).